# Importing vega-embed after installation

Tags: angular, vega-lite, vega, vegas-viz, vega-embed

I have installed `vega` & `vega-lite` & `vega-embed` using `npm` and now I am following the instructions [here](https://github.com/vega/vega-embed) on how to embed a graph into my own page (**not display it inside vs-code** as the `vega-embed` extension does).

I have written the following code in my **Angular app** which throws errors:

*vega.component.html*

```
<h3 class="center">Vega Viz</h3>

<figure id="vega" class="center"></figure>
```

*vega.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import embed from 'vega-embed';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-vega',
  templateUrl: './vega.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vega.component.css']
})
export class VegaComponent implements OnInit {

  svg: any;

  margin = 50;
  width = 750 - (this.margin * 2);
  height = 400 - (this.margin * 2);

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createSvg();
    this.embedGraph();
  }

  createSvg(): void {
    this.svg = d3
      .select("figure#vega")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", this.width + (this.margin * 2))
      .attr("height", this.height + (this.margin * 2))
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin + "," + this.margin + ")");
  }

  async embedGraph(): Promise<void> {
    const spec = "/assets/density-heatmaps.vg.json";
    embed.vegaEmbed("figure#vega", spec);
    const result = await embed("figure#vega", spec);
    console.log(result.view);
  }
}
```

I put one of the examples `density-heatmaps.vg.json` in my Angular's `assets` folder and would like to display it inside my `http://localhost:4200` page.

At first, I thought it was the main code that was causing the errors, but then I realized it is actually the **import** line at the top that is crashing my app...

Could someone please help me understand why the import statement crashes the app and how I can fix it?

Afterward, I can continue working on my code and get the graphic to show in my `html figure` area hopefully...

By the way, I have tried both `import embed from 'vega-embed'` and `import * as embed from 'vega-embed'` but both crash the app. I would appreciate any help.

***p.s.*** Here is a screenshot of my inspect console:

[image]

I searched for `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` thinking that it is a flag I can set to true for allowing the import, but I found nothing in the app...

The contents of my config files are as follows:

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "a-chis-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
    "d3": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "vega": "^5.20.2",
    "vega-embed": "^6.18.2",
    "vega-lite": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/d3": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "strict": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to create a minimal version of your issue in an isolated environment like Stackblitz? I tried importing + installing vega-embed in an angular starter, and it works: https://a.cl.ly/xQu6ZmmR / https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-getting-started-s3qsnr

Build issues are hard to debug without access to your code: can you post package.json or any build related config (like tsconfig.json )? 

You may also need to install vega  and vega-lite  as peer dependencies, they're not automatically provided if you just installed vega-embed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When you say "it works", do you mean you created a new Angular project, along with a vega `ts` and `html`, and your importing and that method in the script all work fine? By the way, I have installed all the dependencies, as I mention in my post. I will add the config files shortly... Thank you

Comment: @CameronYick I copied my code into a blank project on stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q4nw99?file=src/app/app.component.ts) and [here](https://angular-q4nw99.stackblitz.io) but this component is one of many components, so I just renamed the `selector` to `app` and put the content into `app.html` and `app.component.ts`. Please let me know if you can help, I would be grateful.

Comment: By "it works", I just meant that vega-embed was importing without creating an error. Glad to hear see you were able to find the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the `import` issue by adding `"esModuleInterop": true` and `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` to my `tsconfig.json` file:.

My file now looks like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

[This](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowSyntheticDefaultImports) page prompted the solution.